# Algorithm to find the number of neighbour atoms for each atom sparsely located in a 3D cubic system

Tags: graph-theory

Imagine a scenario where a number of atoms are located at random places in a 3D grid. We have 3D coordinates for each atom. I would like to find the number of neighbors for each atom, neighbors being defined as atoms 1 unit distance away from the atom. If the grid were fully packed with atoms, each atoms would have 6 neighbors. How to find the number of neighbor atoms (or the number of connected edges) if the atoms were sparsely distributed and we just know the coordinate position of each atom?

Answer (score 0):

It hardly depends on the numbers involved and on the tradeoff you look for between space and time performances.

Let $A$ be the set of agents (atoms) and let $n$ be the number of agents (atoms) -- namely $n = |A|$ --.
Let $m$ be the size of the lattice so that you can have $m^3$ spots.

Additionally, you have to consider how frequently the agents move (update their position) and if the movement is localised or if it allows jumps.

The simplest algorithm to determine mutual neighbourhood relations is clearly the pair-wise comparison which has space cost $\mathcal O(n)$ and time cost $\mathcal O(n^2)$.

Assuming this solution is not optimal for your purposes, you can think of many approaches depending on the information above-mentioned.

If the space is not a constraint (or $n \sim m$), you can create three vectors $x_c, y_c$ and $z_c$ of size $m$ holding sets where you store the agents by index, that is if $a \in A$ has coordinates $a_x$, $a_y$ and $a_z$, then $x_c[a_x].\texttt{add}(a)$, $y_c[a_y].\texttt{add}(a)$ and $z_c[a_z].\texttt{add}(a)$ (we denote with $.\texttt{add}(a)$ to add the id of $a$ in the set).
Clearly, the solution is space-expensive since it requires $\mathcal O(m)$ but it is time-cheap since checking the adjacency only requires checking for the agents that share two out of three coords sets collecting a total time of $\mathcal O(n)$.
Do note also that you should keep in mind that coords array must be updated each time an agent moves.

Another approach is to build three arrays as before to keep the agents ordered by their $x$-, $y$- and $z$-coords. Building such arrays requires $\mathcal O(n\cdot\log n)$ and looking for a specific element requires $\mathcal O(\log n)$. However, the advantage is that now you will know which agents are in the proximity of a specific agent and it requires $3n$ in space only (compared to $\mathcal O(m)$ of the previous approach).
The total time hence results in $\mathcal O (n \cdot \log n)$ for the construction, $\Theta (n \cdot \log n)$ for the neighbourhood creation and $\Theta (\log n)$ for the update of a single agent.

Depending on the sparsity, the previous two solutions can be implemented also using a single coord vector to speed up the searches.

Finally, a common solution in ABS (Agent-Based simulations) is to create a voxelization of the space. Namely, you coarsen the grid by creating a disjoint representation of the space and then keep track of the agents in each voxel. This way you know a priori which agents could be neighbours of which agent (do remember to keep an eye for manhattan-1 close voxels) and you can apply the pair-wise test faster.

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned by **@eOnofri**, a very common solution is to use [cell lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cell_lists). If the
size of your space is very big compared to the number of your atoms, the cells can be stored in a dictionary for space efficiency.

From this representation you can compute the [unit disk graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_disk_graph), which is a graph where the vertices represent the atoms, and the edges are the pair of atoms within unit distance. This graph can be computed in linear time (with regards to the number of neighbors atoms) by taking a cell diameter smaller than the unit distance. For each atom, you compute its distance with atoms in neighboring cells (cells that are within one unit distance) except its own cell because every atom in this cell are already known to be within a unit distance. An analysis can show that the number of checked pairs is linear compared to the total number of neighbors atoms. See this paper for more details:
*Bentley, Jon Louis; Stanat, Donald F.; Williams, E. Hollins jun.*, [**The complexity of finding fixed-radius near neighbors**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0020-0190(77)90070-9), Inf. Process. Lett. 6, 209-212 (1977). [ZBL0373.68041](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0373.68041).